# Error on opening database OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

This is the error (edited):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database 'remote:192.168.1.129/test'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:204)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:168)
    at learn.kenji.com.KenjiLearnOrient.main(KenjiLearnOrient.java:10)
```

This has been very weird, I followed exactly as mentioned here http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Document-Database.html using this code

```
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:192.168.1.129/test").open("root", "mypass123");        
    // CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT AND FILL IT
    ODocument doc = new ODocument("Person");
    doc.field("name", "Luke");
    doc.field("surname", "Skywalker");
    doc.field("city", new ODocument("City").field("name", "Rome").field("country", "Italy"));

    // SAVE THE DOCUMENT
    doc.save();
    db.close();
```

I was able to connect via console

```
connect remote:192.168.1.129/test root mypass123
```

I wonder what is it that I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Updated the question @IvanMainetti

Comment: it's very strange, I'm trying your exact code (just modifying the db path and pwd) on Orient v2.2.5. I got no errors and the record is created.

Comment: Still trying to find out whats wrong, maybe my dependencies perhaps? @IvanMainetti

Comment: which orient version are you using?

Comment: @IvanMainetti I am using currently the latest on web which is 2.2.5. I wonder which enterprise, core and client version did you use? enterprise i use 2.1.9, core and client 2.2.4

Comment: Is your server up and running on 192.168.1.129 ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect via console but couldnt using java API driver. @OleksandrGubchenko

Comment: what do you mean "enterprise i use 2.1.9, core and client 2.2.4"? I use 2.2.5 enterprise server, and 2.2.5 libraries in my java project. You need to use same versions in both client and server side.

Comment: I'm talking about the jar mentioned in http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Document-Database.html where i needed to include these jars when using the Document Database interface connected to a remote server (not local/embedded mode) @IvanMainetti